# My dropdown has autopostback set to on, it fills a textbox field based on selection but it is also reloading other postback events

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have an Owner DropDown menu, when the user selects Owner it automatically populates premiseID textField.  I want to modify the code of ifPostBack such that it doesnt refresh loadOtherSpecimenType when I go back to change the Owner.

I was not able to modify the OnSelectedIndexChanged method because its called again and again on the page.

My aspx file:

```
<div class="row form-group form-group-sm">
<div class="col-xs-2">
<asp:Label ID="lblOwner" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" 
      Text="*Owner:"></asp:Label
  </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOwner" aria-label="Owner" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState ="true" CssClass="form-control" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOwner_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvOwner" runat="server" Enabled="true"
     SetFocusOnError="true"
     ErrorMessage="Required" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="ddlOwner" 
     ForeColor="Red"
     ValidationGroup="vGrpPreview" EnableClientScript="true"
     Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </div
     </div>
```

aspx.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  //Some code here

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("");
                    loadOtherSpecimenType();
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    /*
                     If (guuest){
                        load textboxes for DVM, Billing Owner, Copty To
                    }
                    else { //code below */
                    getDdlDVM();
                    getDdlBillTo();
                    getDdlCopyTo();
                    getDdlOwner();
                    getDdlSpecies();
                    var referer1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
```

My OnSelectedIndexChanged function:

```
 protected void ddlOwner_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string _username = "";
            if (Session["username"] != null)
            {
                _username = Session["username"].ToString();
            }
            if (_username != string.Empty)
            {
                if (dbconn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    dbconn.Close();
                }
                dbconn.Open();
                string owner = QuoteHandler(this.ddlOwner.SelectedItem.ToString());

                string query = "select * from ( " +
                     "SELECT  b.id,b.premiseID,b.lname,b.fname,b.lname +case when len(b.fname)> 0 then ', ' + b.fname else '' end + " +
                                    "case when len(b.mname)> 0 then ' ' + b.mname else '' " +
                                    "end + ' - ' + b.city + ', ' + b.state as ddlOwner,[OwnerKey] " +
                                    "from [ADRDL_OwnerInfo] AS b INNER JOIN [ADRDL_ClinicInfo] AS c   " +
                                    "ON c.ClinicKey=b.ClinicKey " +
                                    "WHERE username='" + _username + "' and b.[adminAction]= 'Active' and b.OwnerKey is not null) t where ddlOwner= '" + owner + "';";

                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbconn);
                tablerdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (tablerdr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (tablerdr.Read())
                    {
                        ddlPremiseID.Text = tablerdr["premiseID"].ToString();
                    }
                    tablerdr.Close();
                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        \\code for catch statement
        \\end of code
```

what can I do to my Page_Load function to make sure when I change the Owner selection the postback doesn't reload the loadSpecimenType function.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the field that initiated the postback, and only performing the dependent dropdown population accordingly (when the Owner changes)? You might need to refactor your Page_Load a bit, but that's where I would start.

Comment: How can I capture the field?  and thank you for your response, David.

Comment: In your server-side code (codebehind), look at Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]. That will return the name of the control that initiated the postback.

Comment: I couldn't find Request.Form["_EVENTTRAGET]. I know my Owner dropdown initiated the postback... I have few other functions where the autopostback is on

Comment: It's Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]  (two leading underscores there). To control which other dropdowns you populate, you need to know that one caused the postback.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general way or notion regarding how you might modify `Page_Load` to prevent a certain function from firing when `ddlOwner` induces an autopostback - this may not exactly fit your use case, but it illustrates the way the `__EVENTTARGET` was intended to be used, and you should be able to tailor it to your specific requirement:

Note: I observe in your original post you have an event handler defined for `OnSelectedIndexChanged` for `ddlOwner`, but that handler is not shown, so I can't say if it needs to be modified.

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        // If we are posting back, AND the inducing postback control is *NOT* 
        // the owner dropdown, reload the specimen type
        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != ddlOwner.ClientID)
        {
            loadOtherSpecimenType();
        }else
        {
           // other code here //
        }
   } 
   else
   {
      // code for non-postback load here
   }
}
```